# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/polyfill' in /src

Tags: webpack, babel-polyfill

I'm using webpack with babel, vanillaJS for web clone project. when I trying to run the webpack `("dev:assets": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=development webpack -w")` , then this error comes out.

```
ERROR in multi @babel/polyfill ./assets/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/polyfill' in 'C:\Users\82106\wetube'      
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./assets/js/main.js main[0]
```

someone recommended me to install 'core-js', but error still exist.

here's my github.

```
1. webpack.config.js
https://github.com/miri9/wetube/blob/master/webpack.config.js

2. package config json file
https://github.com/miri9/wetube/blob/master/package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I added this `"@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",` to my dev dependencies in package.json and ran `npm install`. That resolved the issue.